# jquery ajax don't get more than one value from php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I try to use jQuery ajax call to retrive some data via php script.
Script take from mysql table all values of column 'rezhour' what also based on $_GET variable.

Then he print all finded values via json_encode() function

**PHP:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$fromdate = $_GET['fromdate'];
$getrezhiredh = mysql_query("
    SELECT rezhour FROM rezhiredhours 
    WHERE rezdate = '".$fromdate."' ORDER BY rezhour
");

$i=0;
$data = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getrezhiredh)){ 
      $data['hours'][$i] = $row['rezhour']; 
      $i++; 
}

$result = array(
     $data 
);
print json_encode($result);
?>
```

When script is called from browser adress bar all is fine and in we have correct result as below:

```
[{"hours":["2","9","13","14"]}]
```

Each digit in result above corresponds selected table row.

The problem is when i want to do the same via ajax.

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
var date = jQuery('input').val()
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "fromdate="+date,
    url: "script.php",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
</script>
```

Now all is fine only when mysql query return result with one row and this looks in console like this:

```
[{"hours":["1"]}]
```

When mysql query return result with more than one row console show this:

[[]]

For me is really weird that jquery ajax call have problem to print correct result when we have more than one rows with selected data.

What i must do to have the same result in AJAX?

**EDIT:**

*I found an important clue. The problem is WHERE clause in MYSQL query. When u remove from query this clause, php script return data from entire table and now ajax can print into console all selected values from specifed column.
The problem is i must use WHERE clause to load only data from before selected date at the website. Any idea how to do this?*

Comment: `dataType: "html",` change to `dataType: "json",`

Comment: This is don't change anything... instead in console i got 'Array [ Object ]' when mysql return one row, and 'Array [ Array[0] ]' (which means same as [[]]) when return more ...

Comment: It does not matter.. still i have same results... i really think You are trying to find cause in wrong places :-)

Comment: sorry misread the tags, its not app to this q! have you visited the url to make sure the json is outputting correctly? you can simulate posts with a chrome ext called adv rest client.

Comment: I wrote above in my post "When script is called from browser adress bar all is fine and  we have correct result as below:", so yes, i visited url directly to check what script returns... in this case all is correct... only when i use ajax to got same result problem appears

Comment: I use data: { fromdate: date } and remove dataType. When dataType is removed script use type based on header from php script.. in this case as 'html'... anyway , still i got the same results

Comment: Echo your query in ajax script and then run the ajax and see the query return in console. Whatever the query is echoing, execute that query in mysql.

Comment: Try to form url youself: remove parameter 'data' from ajax settings, and 'url:parameter' looks like 'url:"script.php?formdate=2015-30-27"'. The url must be the one that shows correct result in browser.

Comment: @unconnected : When in ajax code i use manually typed url, just copy of browser url, indeed i have in console result which i need.So 'url: "script.php?fromdate=1448665200",' put correct result into console, but 'url: "script.php?fromdate="+date,' is not!!! So the problem is that i use var date to specify date in query url. So weird url parameter with jquery variable do not work, but this with manually typed do. How it possible?

Comment: @X9DESIGN I guess it's because of datetime format and/or string concatination. The right way is to use data:{fromdate:date}. Check the value of date in console, I think it would be smth you ain't expecting.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return json data ,must use dataType:json. Valid data format is data :{key:value},...

```
var date = jQuery('input').val();
jQuery.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
data: {fromdate : date },
url: "script.php",
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
});
```